# Magento 2.3 performance drop after running php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, setup-di-compile, magento-cron

While working on a development instance I installed the stripe payment module and then ran

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I hadn't previously done this on this install and it's been running for over a month totally stable and with acceptable performance for a small aws instance. However since this was run the performance of the system has dropped to unacceptable levels and pins php7.2-fpm to 100%.

It's so slow even the cron jobs start backing up and consuming more and more cpu time.

Any ideas what might be going on and what I can do to debug it?

**EDIT**
I've added new relic onto the system and can see the following

```
Category    Slowest components  Count   Duration    %
Custom  Magento\Framework\Config\Dom::_mergeNode    731 38,700 ms   53%
Custom  Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem::_readFiles  18  7,950 ms    11%
Custom  Magento\Framework\Config\Dom::_getMatchedNode   113 5,020 ms    7%
Custom  Magento\Framework\Config\Dom::validateDomDocument   8   2,790 ms    4%
Custom  Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Mapper\Dom::convert  7   2,740 ms    4%
Custom  Magento\WebapiAsync\Code\Generator\Config\RemoteServiceReader\Communication::read   1   2,570 ms    4%
Remainder   Remainder   1   12,700 ms   18%
Total time          72,500 ms   100%
```

Comment: First check your current instance mod is production/ develop.Also Some when we install new extension then check cache is disabled at the system.If yes then you need to enable all cache also mod should be production.

Comment: Amit, the performance is the same in develop or production, the cache is enabled also

Comment: but performance should better at production than the develop. Please check bot attack happening on your system. I have faced  performance issue due a large amount of bot attach and it has been resolved by add web firewall / & upgrade /applied magento  patches

Comment: This is a development system not connected to the wider internet so no not a bot attack.

Comment: Have you looked into size of php fpm worker count. Although you've not said whether your dev is using production data or not. Could be you've reached a point in terms of data i.e. number of categories vs products which requires more resource

Answer (score 3):

**Edited - This didn't work**

Finally found the solution to this, it appears the for some reason when doing the di compile the system had turned the cache off or somehow otherwise invalidated it but the status still showed as on when doing

```
php /bin/magento cache:status
```

I fixed it by running

```
php bin/magento cache:disable
php bin/magento cache:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

This seems to have reset everything back to a working state.

**update**
So this seemed to work for a short period, performance then reverted to very poor levels. I've disabled all 3rd party and custom modules, cleared the cache, deleted the generated/ folder, tried default mode, developer mode and production to no effect.

Comment: Awesome. The admin shows all green but everything was set to 0. Now set to 1 and cron runs in 2s instead of 20 :)

Comment: Have you solved the other issues ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and it turned out it was caused by running `composer update` as described in this bug report: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17634#issuecomment-492500726

You can sometimes fix it by running `bin/magento cache:enable`, but sometimes you'll need to go into `env.php` and manually edit the `cache_types` section to look like this:

```
    'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'target_rule' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'compiled_config' => 1
    ],
```